# Multiple Relative frequency histogram in R, ggplot

Tags: ggplot2, histogram, frequency

I'm trying to plot multiple histograms of relative frequencies in R. ggplot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below are some basic example with the build-in `iris` dataset. The relative part is obtained by multiplying the density with the binwidth.

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, fill = Species)) +
  geom_histogram(aes(y = after_stat(density * width)),
                 position = "identity", alpha = 0.5)
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
```

[image]

```r
ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length)) +
  geom_histogram(aes(y = after_stat(density * width))) +
  facet_wrap(~ Species)
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-03-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>